# Carthrob + Stripe International Country

Tags: cartthrob, shipping, stripe

I'm using Carthrob + Stripe. I'm using the boilerplate, {gateway_fields} to render my checkout fields. However, I don't see the country select menu. Is this not there by default? I'm attempting to set pricing for international shipping, however, without a country select I can't. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you check your CT settings (Cartthrob > Settings > Payments) and you have your gateway set to Stripe you should see an "HTML Template" setting, which if left to Default, will display the HTML generated by the {gateway_fields} tag. It doesn't include a country select.

You can copy this code and add it, along with a select tag for your country field, to your template of choice - or set said template right there on that page to continue using the {gateway_fields} tag.

Comment: So will the GLOBAL rules for shipping cost still work if I create a country select menu? Assuming I would give it an ID of #country?

Comment: I think you'll most likely want to use the country select tag built into cartthrob as part of a cart update to get the customer's location and calculate the shipping cost. You can do so along with your per location shipping rates. I think you'll find specific examples and answers within the CT docs.